# git monorepo with multiple deployment pipeline on GCP

Tags: git, docker, google-cloud-platform, deployment, devops

I am looking for some guidance on how you may approach the deployment of this repo. It is a monorepo, but it contains 3 different services that I want to deploy separately on github.

With that, I would want as well to include some CI/CD for automatic build and deployment of those services.

Here is the file structure

```
File Structure
shared_module
  # contains shared functions accross all services
Service 1
  main.py
  test_main.py
  dockerfile
Service 2
  main.py
  test_main.py
  dockerfile
Service 3
  main.py
  test_main.py
  dockerfile
```

In GCP, I have each service registered within the container registry. Currently, they are being manually shipped and we manually built them again to be available on production.

Comment: The specifics of your CI/CD pipeline will change depending on what service you use (github actions, circleCI, travisCI, ...).

Generally, it looks like you'll need 4 steps in your pipeline

 1. build (and cache) each service (and docker image)
 2. Test each build (if you have tests)
 3. deploy each image to container registry (you'll need to give your CI/CD service an access key for this)
 4. deploy builds to server (CI/CD service needs access key to server for this)

This pipeline can be triggered on merge's into specific branches.

Comment: @smcrowley In the suggested flow, how can I trigger an automatic built for only one service that is changed? IOW I don't want to rebuilt a service if no work has been done on it.

Comment: https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter. you'd make a 'check' job for each service, and then make the deploy jobs for those services depend on the check. if no files were changed, no deployments happen. This way, you can still build and test all services together, but only deploy ones that have changes

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much, great information on here!